# Laravel 5.2 belongstoMany in views

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, laravel-5

I'm trying to make a belongstoMany relationship in Laravel 5.2.39 between people and places but am unable to pass the information into a view in a select box. I just get: "Error Exception: Undefined variable: people". It also is not saving and making the pivot table entries.

I have created the pivot table person_place with 'place_id' and 'person_id' columns which correspond to the 'people' and 'places' table.

**App/Person.php** (Person Model)

```
<?php
namespace ss;
use ss\Place;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Person extends Model
{
    /**
     * Fillable fields
     * 
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'type',
        'status',
        'notes',
        'email',
        'phone',
        'alt',
        'web',
        'first',
        'last',
        'title',
    ];

    public function places()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Place');
    }
}
```

**App/Place.php** (Place Model)

```
<?php
namespace ss;
use ss\Person;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Place extends Model
{
    /**
     * Fillable fields
     * 
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'type',
        'status',
        'notes',
        'email',
        'phone',
        'alt',
        'web',
        'address1',
        'address2',
        'city',
        'state',
        'zip',
        'country',
    ];

    public function people()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Person');
    }

}
```

**App/Http/Controllers/PlaceController.php** (Places Controller)

```
 <?php namespace ss\Http\Controllers;
use ss\Place;
use ss\Person;
use ss\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use View;
use Session;

class PlaceController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $places = Place::all();
        $people = Person::pluck('name','id')->all();

        return View::make('places.index', compact('places','people'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $people = Person::lists('last', 'id');

        return view('places.create', compact('people'));
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required'
        ]);

        $input = $request->all();
        Place::create($input);

        Session::flash('flash_message', 'Place successfully added!');
        return redirect()->action('PlaceController@index');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $place = Place::findOrFail($id);
        return view('places.show')->withPlace($place);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $place = Place::findOrFail($id);
        $people = Person::pluck('name','id')->all();

        return view('places.edit', compact('place','people'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function update($id, Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required'
        ]);

        $input = $request->except('people');

        $place = Place::findOrFail($id);
            $peopleIDs = $this->place->people($peopleIds);

        $place->fill($input)->save();
        Session::flash('flash_message', 'Place successfully edited!');
        return redirect()->action('PlaceController@index', $place);
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $place = Place::findOrFail($id);
        $place->delete();

        Session::flash('flash_message', 'Place successfully deleted!');
        return redirect()->action('PlaceController@index');
    }

}
```

**resources/views/places/edit.blade.index.php** (Places View, where I'm trying to build select list -not working)

```
@section('aside')
        {!! Form::select('people', $people, null, ['class' => '', 'multiple']) !!}

<ul class="section table-of-contents">
    <li><a href="#introduction">New Time</a></li>
    <li><a href="#structure">New Money</a></li>
    <li> </li>
    <li><a href="#initialization">New Sub-Task</a></li>
</ul>
@endsection
```

**resources/views/places/create.blade.index.php** (Places View with a select list that works but does not make a pivot table when saving)

```
@section('aside')
            {!! Form::select('people', $people, null, ['class' => '', 'multiple']) !!}
@endsection
```

Have tried various methods of "with" and "attach" and am unable to get a result. Interestingly, even if I specifically place "$person = "foo"; in my edit method it still says it is undefined.

Thank you for your help.

EDIT: Updated Code

Comment: If I had to bet, I would say that PHP's `compact()` is not playing nicely with Laravel's `view()`. Did you try passing a standard array, like `array('people' => $people)`?

Comment: Thank you for this. I'm fairly new and I don't understand the differences yet when to use ->with and when to use compact($,$). I updated the code above with fiddling and have gotten it to work. But perhaps this is related to the reason why I can't save new ones. `$place->people()->sync($input);` is the closest I can get, but it does not work right (it puts the whole array into the database and makes a ton of bogus records.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the PlacesController, your `edit($id)` method does not pass an array of people to the view.

```
/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    $place = Place::findOrFail($id);
    $people = People::pluck('name','id')->all();
    return view('places.edit', compact('place', 'people');
}
```

Comment: Can't edit my post because the editor is bugged for some reason, it automatically deletes stuff when I write. Anyway, I wanted to add about the update method that you can use `Place::people()->sync($peopleIds);` to update the Ids in your pivot table when a user adds or deletes a person from the select box. `attach()` and `detach()` are usually used for manually adding and removing ids from the pivot table.

Comment: I worked with that code a bit and got it functioning (updated original question). However, I cannot get the information from your edit to work. Then I just add Place::people()->sync($peopleIds); I get `Non-static method ss\Place::people() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context` I know there is no variable for $peopleIds but the class is definitely there and namespaced.

Comment: The $peopleIds should come from the input people like `$peopleIds = $request->get('people');` and the people() method is usually the name of the relationship method (assuming you called it people). 

Try either Place::with('people')->people()->sync($peopleIds) or don't use the facade, use constructor dependency injection and call is like `$this->place->people($peopleIds);`. I don't use facades in my controllers.

Comment: Oh and use `$request->except('people');` instead of `$request->all()` for the `$input` variable in the `update($id)` method, so you can ignore the select box and avoid errors.

Comment: (Sorry hit enter too fast) I'm totally not getting something at all. Now I am getting `Undefined property: ss\Http\Controllers\PlaceController::$place`. Is there a good resource for setting up Many To Many relationships in Laravel? Failing miserably and I can only assume it is because of my lack of understanding and trying to follow along to documentation that probably isn't for the right version. And trying to substitute the most common example, Blog and Tags, with my own People, Places and surely mixing something up somewhere! Thank you for all of your help. I need to do some heavy reading.

Comment: You can either follow the 5.2 version of the documentation and do the task list apps or you can start from scratch and go to [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/). [Laravel 5 From Scratch](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-from-scratch) will be useful to you for now :)

Comment: Thank you so much. I am in over my head now because I don't understand what's going on at all. Too many questions! I'm sure your suggestions would have worked had I understood how to implement them properly :) I will check out the Laracasts video as I watched some of hose before and it was great but I thought I had watched all the free ones. Thank you again for your help.